# How do I print out text in subscript/superscript in JQuery Terminal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-terminal

I've been trying to find a way to print out text in subscript/superscript within terminal.echo(), but I haven't found one.

I know that you can add color and make text bold using the following

```
 return "[[gb;teal;black]" + message + "]";
```

...but is there a similar way to make it subscript/superscript (e.g., x<sup>superscript</sup> or x<sub>subscript</sub>)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use raw HTML

```js
term.echo('x<sup>Superscript</sup> or x<sub>Subscript</sub>', { raw: true });
```